# displaying result based on 2 values from parameter table

Tags: filtering, powerquery

I have bug report which has bugs and creator of it. like following

[Image for referring sample about my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p6Wq.png)

1)Is it possible to see records by giving input as A and B only and how many bugs they logged.

2)is it possible to see how many bugs A logged

3)see all the bugs logged by all creators.

I was able to achieve 2 and 3 using table + parameter from single table. but how can we do this for 1st? is it possible using the one common table for all 3 requirements or some other approach?

I am giving following code for the 2nd and 3rd point. Please help for 1st.

let
    ANDCriteria01 = Creator

```
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\something\Desktop\xls\bugs.xlsx"), null, true),
VSTS_e4c50440_d467_4aa3_a3e8_4a3bb8fb4d71_Table = Source{[Item="VSTS_e4c50440_d467_4aa3_a3e8_4a3bb8fb4d71",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(VSTS_e4c50440_d467_4aa3_a3e8_4a3bb8fb4d71_Table,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Work Item Type", type text}, {"Title", type text}, {"Created By", type text}, {"Assigned To", type text}, {"State", type text}}),

#"Filtered Rows"= if names= "All" then Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each true) else Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Created By] = Creator
```

in
    #"Filtered Rows"

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use 1 parameter "names" with either "All" or the required names, separated by commas.

```
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each if names = "All" then true else List.Contains(Text.Split(names,","), [Created By]))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!! I made some changes to table in excel like I added a,b,c as to replacement option to all from my table.so now my table has a,b,c as individual options which will show defects logged by them and when I select a,b,c it will show all the bugs logged by all people.

And made changes to code like #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each List.Contains(Text.Split(names,","),[Created By]))

so I even without if it works as i expected it to.